# Can I catch Lunkers in my Garrison?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I did the 7 achievements today where you have to catch 100 enormous fish of each type in order to get the Quest where one can gain Nat Pagle as a follower.

I read a guide [here](http://www.elsanglin.com/catching_lunkers.html), but it does not detail if I can catch Lunkers in my Garrison. However, the Garrison does satisfy the requirement for catching them:

> - The type of Lunker caught depends on the zone being fished: The Lunker name is the same name as the prize fish caught from each zone's
>     inland waters (as visited during the quest, A True Draenor Angler,
>     list above).
> - Lunkers can only be caught from inland open water, not pools.
> - Lunkers are caught with or without Bait. Bait makes no difference to Lunker catches, but does continue to influence the main catch.
> - Lunkers are caught alongside another fish. They are caught alongside approximately 1.2% of the catch (currently 26 out of an open water
>     sample of 2100). There is no obvious variation by skill or zone.
> - Lunkers are bound when caught, so cannot be traded. They are "unique (5)", which means that you can only hold 5 lunkers (of each type) in
>     your inventory at once. With 5, you will not be able to catch
>     additional lunkers of the same type.

So according to this list, one should be able to catch them there, some confirmation would be good though, which is why I ask here if anyone has actually caught a Lunker while fishing in the Garrison.

---

EDIT

The rule that you cannot catch them from pools, seems not to be right. I was able to catch a Lunker right here:

[image: Screenshot of fishing spot]

This is at the entrance of Frostfire Ridge, which would qualify as a pool normally. So it seems not to only drop in open waters. I still did not catch a Lunker in my Garrison though.

Comment: The water in the garrison looks like a pool to me. I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was able to catch a Lunker here too: http://i.imgur.com/MlNhgNF.jpg Which would be a pool/pond too, by your definition. So it is not really clear imho. (Text is German, Oschi equals Lunker)

Comment: I was wrong about the pools in the garrison. There aren't any. :) And I don't see one in your picture either; this is clear since the Fire Ammonite pools are very distinctive and easy to see, but other ones sometimes aren't if your graphics settings are not just perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Pool in World of Warcraft fishing refers to the small glowing circles that spawn in the water and give better chances of catching the fish that belong to the pool.

Fishing in open water referes to not fishing in one of said pools.

Source: 10 years of playing wow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they changed it. I don't know. I just caught a [Sea Scorpion Lunker](http://www.wowhead.com/item=122696/sea-scorpion-lunker) today from a Sea Scorpion pool in southern FrostRidge. Down by the [Pale Fishmonger](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=78606/pale-fishmonger).